# Riemann-Lebesgue equivalence for n-dimensional integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

"Lebesgue's Theorem" states that for any *bounded* $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is Riemann Integrable iff $m\{x:f  \text{ is not continuous at x }\}=0$, and if so Riemann's integral coincides with Lebesgue's. ($m$ is Lebesgue's measure).

Does there exist a generalization of this theorem for higher dimensions? Can I have a proof or a reference please?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935419/characterization-of-riemann-integrability-in-two-dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that the Lebesgue-Riemann theorem states that $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable if, and only if, $f$ is *bounded* and is continuous almost everywhere (if a function is not bounded, it can't be Riemann integrable).

A proof of the more general result for multivariable functions can be found in volume 1 of "Real Analysis" by Duistermaat. A better exercise in fact will be to take this wiki [proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) and adapt it to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Shouldn't "almost always" be "almost everywhere"?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff corrected, thanks.

Comment: Could you please state the generalization?

Comment: I have failed to locate a book called "Real Analysis" by Duistermaat. There exists a book called "Multidimensional Real Analysis" by Duistermaat and Kolk. Its second volume deals with multivariable Riemann integration. I have also failed to locate either single- or multivariable Lebesgue-Riemann theorem in either volume.

Comment: @Max it's been a good few years since I had written this answer. I may very well have made a mistake about the reference.

Comment: For the record, I think @IttayWeiss was referring to Volume 2 of "Multidimensional real Analysis" by Duistermaat and Kolk, and in particular to Theorem 6.3.2, which basically states that for a bounded set A,  $\mathbf{1}_A$ is integrable in the sense of Riemann if and only if the boundary of A has vanishing measure. Of course, this doesn't cover "general functions" but it's a good starting point.